# How do I delete my account and all questions?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I wish to delete my account and questions as I do not want to waste anyone's time answering my posts. The links I have to get support to do it do not work. Please advise. Regards

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/help/deleting-account

Comment: Also https://askubuntu.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question

Comment: Consider that the only question you've asked is "What OS should I try on my system".  Neither here on Ask Ubuntu nor on Unix and Linux our sister site are those questions 'suitable' questions for the site - they only generate lists of solutions "Try {INSERT_DISTRIBUTION_HERE}".  This alone is *not* a case of "I am not a suitable member" and more a case of simply not understanding how the site works (please read the Help Center, and https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic specifically)

Answer (score 2):

In response to an answer to your only question asked on the main site, you wrote:

> The two responses I have received here have convinced me that I am not a suitable member of this elitist club and I will retire graciously and apologise for taking up your valuable time

If you still feel that way, the simplest option would be to just not visit the site any more.